# is it possible to open a html page stocked in local storage with iframe element in reactJs app?

Tags: reactjs

I am building a reactjs app and inside my app I am using an iframe to load an html file which has it's own jquery scripts which are stored in in the public folder and it works fine. the html page is loaded and execute it's scripts.

```
 <iframe id="myIframe" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0"
            style={{position:"absolute", height: "100%", width:"100%"}}
            src="./player.html"/>
```

now I have an endpoint that sending me the html file and it's scripts and I am willing to store this files in locale storage. So my question is it is possible to animate the iframe with the decoded local storage files (path problem ) and if not is there another solution for doing this ? 
Thank you for your help !

Comment: Why are you storing the files in localstorage? Are you not able to add javascript directly to player.html? Do you want to be able to control player.html from the main site?

Comment: the player.html is related to many jquery scripts that manipulate the file it's an independent project that my company built to manipulate a magazine. So to avoid rebuilding all the project with react we decide to call it independently.  And for the local storage each user can download magazines so I have to store this magazines in local storage to let the user access to his magazines and don't give him the right to download those magazines to not share it with others. He will have to access to those magazines from inside the app and can read them in offline mode.